# Error I get with python when testing webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-3.5

I am trying to test out selenium webdriver for python3.5 and i keep getting a error i already downloaded pip
 MY CODE-

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import keys
 driver= webdriver.FireFox()
 driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

ERROR MESSAGE-

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File "C:\Users\nasir_000\OneDrive\Documents\selenium.py", line 1, in 
 from selenium import webdriver
 File "C:\Users\nasir_000\OneDrive\Documents\selenium.py", line 1, in 
 from selenium import webdriver
 ImportError: cannot import name 'webdriver'
```

Answer (score 0):

These are case sensitive words. Where you have '**keys**' you should have '**Keys**' and where you have '**FireFox**' you should have '**Firefox**'

The following code works as intended:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver= webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```